# generating a spoofed UDP packet in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, spoofing

how can i create a spoofed UDP packet using python sockets,without using scapy library.
i have created the socket like this

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(bytes('', "utf-8"), ('192.168.1.9', 7043))# 192.168.1.9dest 7043 dest port
```

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: @ZhouQuan the question is how i can create a spoofed UDP packet,i mean that how i can change the source ip (my computer ip) to something else random.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the first results for google searches like "spoofing udp packet python" so I am going to expand @Cukic0d's answer using scapy.

Using the scapy CLI tool (some Linux distributions package it separately to the scapy Python library ):

```py
pkt = IP(dst="1.1.1.1")/UDP(sport=13338, dport=13337)/"fm12abcd"
send(pkt)
```

This sends a UDP Packet to the IP `1.1.1.1` with the source port `13338`, destination port `13337` and the content `fm12abcd`.

If you need to a certain interface for some reason (like sending over a VPN that isn't your default route) you can use `send(pkt, iface='tun0')` to specify it.

One difference to @Cukic0d's answer is that this solution is more flexible by sending a layer 3 packet with `send` instead of a layer 2 packet with `sendp`. So it isn't necessary to prepend the correct Ethernet header with `Ether()` which can cause issues in some scenarios, e.g.:

```
WARNING: Could not get the source MAC: Unsupported address family (-2) for interface [tun0]
WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean changing the source and destination addresses from the IP layer (on which the UDP layer is based).

To do so, you will need to use raw sockets. (SOCK_RAW), meaning that you have to build everything starting from the Ethernet layer to the UDP layer.

Honestly, without scapy, that’s a lot of hard work. If you wanted to use scapy, it would take 2 lines:

```
pkt = Ether()/IP(src=“...”, dst=“...”)/UDP()/...
sendp(pkt)
```

I really advice you to use scapy. The code itself is quite small so I don’t see a reason not to use it. It’s defiantly the easiest in python

Comment: can you provide complete scapy statements for this case?